# When writing AppleScript in Automator, what is the significance of "input" and "parameters"?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

When one adds a "Run AppleScript" action to a file in Automator.app (e.g., a workflow, application, or service), the following default code is presented:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    (* Your script goes here *)

    return input
end run
```

What is the significance of `input` and `parameters`? That is to say,

- Where does the AppleScript code get these variables from?
- To where exactly does the AppleScript `return` the `input` to?
- How might these variables be ideally employed in an AppleScript application/service? Examples are appreciated.

Comment: If you're going to continue to program in AppleScript, I strongly suggest you read the entire [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH208-SW1)

Comment: Also, [About Handlers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-CJBIDBJH) and [Handlers in Script Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW14) as this covers the area of your questions. In brief, this allows for objects to be passed to the _action_ and passed off to the next _action_ but not limited to that.

Comment: _"This allows for objects to be passed to the action and passed off to the next action but not limited to that."_ I understand what this means vaguely, but sometimes I just need someone to explain things to me in a practical sense with examples for me to absorb a concept.

Comment: Also since your using AppleScript mainly in Automator, you should also read the [Automator Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/AutomatorConcepts/Automator.html) and specifically [The Structure of the on run Command Handler](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/AutomatorConcepts/Articles/ImplementScriptAction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001512-97148-CJBIADBH), as the latter specifically covers what you asked.

Answer (score 28):

I'll try to answer my own question, making use of the relevant documentation<sup>1</sup> provided by @user3439894 in a [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270159/when-writing-applescript-in-automator-what-is-the-significance-of-input-and?noredirect=1#comment339472_270159) on my question.

## ***Where does the AppleScript code get these variables from?***

### **`input`**:

> The `input` parameter contains (in most instances) **the output of the previous action in the workflow**.

The data type of `input` is `list`.

To display the contents of `input` in Automator's corresponding *"Results"* pane for that specific action, simply use:

```
return input
```

---

### **`parameters`**:

> The `parameters` parameter contains the **settings made in the action’s user interface**.

The data type of `parameters` is `reco` (i.e., a `record` object).

Here is an overview of the `reco` type<sup>2</sup>:

> This type is used as the type of the `properties` property for the `item` class, and the type of the `with properties` parameters of the `duplicate` and `make` commands.

To display the contents of `parameters` in Automator's corresponding *"Results"* pane for that specific action, simply use:

```
return parameters
```

#### **What, specifically, does `parameters` contain?**

I was curious what exactly is meant by, *"settings made in the action’s user interface,"* so I took a look at the contents of `parameters`. I learned that, unlike `input`, `parameters` only contains information about that specific action, not any information regarding the preceding action.

By using the following line of code,

```
display dialog length of parameters
```

I also discovered that the number of properties in `parameters` for a *"Run AppleScript"* action in Automator is three.

They are:

```
|temporary items path|:
```

where `|temporary items path|` is followed by the file path of the temporary folder created to store temporary data that may be created by the currently running *"Run AppleScript"* action. This folder is necessarily created upon run, even if the code does not create any temporary data. After the *"Run AppleScript"* action has completed, this folder and its parent folder are immediately deleted.

- Note that `|temporary items path|` differs from `(path to temporary items)`.

  - `return POSIX path of (path to temporary items)` produces:

    - > "/private/var/folders/p9/q_5_fbld7qzdmz6htfqjcxhw0000gn/T/TemporaryItems/"
  - `return |temporary items path| of parameters` produces:

    - > "/var/folders/p9/q_5_fbld7qzdmz6htfqjcxhw0000gn/T/1BD6446F-5501-42E5-A002-29588DFF8BD8/1/com.apple.Automator.RunScript"
  - While both folders reside within the "T" folder, the difference between these two folders is that the `|temporary items path|` folder, as well as its parent folder, are deleted upon completion of the *"Run AppleScript"* action (i.e., this folder is action-specific), while the `path to temporary items` folder is never deleted and can be viewed even when the AppleScript is not running.

```
ignoresInput:
```

where `ignoresInput` is either *true* or *false*, depending on whether the *"Ignore this action's input"* box found in the *Options* tab beneath that action in Automator is either ticked or unchecked.

```
source:
```

where `source` contains the unabridged AppleScript code of that *"Run AppleScript"* action.

#### **How does one read the contents of `parameters` within an AppleScript?**

Since the type of `parameters` is not `list`, one cannot simply:

```
set firstParameter to item 1 of parameters
```

as this will produce an error. But, you can convert `parameters` to a `list` object:

```
set parametersInListFormat to (parameters as list)
```

Then, you'll be able to execute something like this:

```
set individualItemFrom_parametersInListFormat to ""

repeat with individualItemFrom_parametersInListFormat in parametersInListFormat
    display dialog individualItemFrom_parametersInListFormat
end repeat
```

Alternatively, you can skip the conversion to a `list` and read the contents of `parameters` simply like so<sup>1</sup>:

```
set item1 to |temporary items path| of parameters
set item2 to |ignoresInput| of parameters
set item3 to source of parameters
```

---

## ***To where exactly does the AppleScript `return` the `input` to?***

The `input` of the current action is sent to the next action as that action's `input`.

More info on the `return` statement<sup>3</sup>:

> A `return` statement exits a handler and optionally returns a specified value. Execution continues at the place in the script where the handler was called.
>
> If a handler does not include a `return` statement, AppleScript returns the value returned by the last statement. If the last statement doesn’t return a value, AppleScript returns nothing.
>
> When AppleScript has finished executing a handler (that is, when it executes a `return` statement or the last statement in the handler), it passes control to the place in the script immediately after the place where the handler was called. If a handler call is part of an expression, AppleScript uses the value returned by the handler to evaluate the expression.

---

## ***How might these variables be ideally employed in an AppleScript application/service?***

Now that I better understand the positional parameters of `input` and `parameters`, it is easier for me to imagine their practical value.

### **`input`**:

The value of `input` is conspicuous and the possibilities for its implementation are immeasurable.

One very basic application would be if you want to pass a string of text that a user enters in a dialog box via an *"Ask for Text"* action to the next action, a *"Run AppleScript"* action that writes this string to file. Here is what this might look like:

[image: Sample Automator Workflow]

---

### **`parameters`**:

Given that `parameters` is limited to that specific action and does not contain any data from previous actions, and the data that it does contain isn't necessarily relevant, it is much less useful and flexible  than `input`. I can visualize the need for `|temporary items path|`, but I am unable to do so for the other two properties.

Here is an example of how one might need to reference `|temporary items path|` in their AppleScript:

- Say that one wanted an Automator application to display to the user the dimensions of a web image.

  - The user could use `|temporary items path|` as a location to store that image, so that the code could operate on it. Then, upon completion, since the user does not need or want the image saved to disk, the AppleScript would automatically delete that image (or, more specifically, the AppleScript would automatically delete the folder that contains the folder that contains that image).
  - Here is how this might be implemented:

    ```
    on run {input, parameters}

        set theURLofImage to "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/se/se-logo.png"
        set tempFolderThatIsAutomaticallyDeletedAfterRun to |temporary items path| of parameters
        set filename to "StackExchangeLogo.png"
        set fullFilepath to tempFolderThatIsAutomaticallyDeletedAfterRun & "/" & filename



        -- Saving image from internet to disk.
        -- From: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21491446/7138483    
        do shell script "curl -f " & theURLofImage & " -o " & fullFilepath



        -- Figuring out the dimensions of the saved image.
        -- From: https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/imageevents/01.html
        try
            tell application "Image Events"
                launch
                set this_image to open fullFilepath
                -- Extract the properties record.
                set the props_rec to the properties of this_image
                -- Purge the open image data.
                close this_image
                -- Extract the property value from the record.
                copy (dimensions of props_rec) to {x, y}
                set the image_info to "Dimensions of " & filename & ": " & "" & x & " x " & y
            end tell
            display dialog image_info
        on error error_message
            display dialog error_message
        end try

        return input
    end run
    ```
- Also, one might want to monitor the size of the `|temporary items path|` folder, to impose a limitation, so that if its size surpasses a certain value, an error is presented to the user.

In terms of how `|ignoresInput|` might be used, one could change the `|ignoresInput|` setting mid-code, with the following line:

```
set |ignoresInput| of parameters to true
```

One might want to arrange their code so that if the `input` meets or does not meet some condition, then the `input` should be ignored. For example:

```
if item 1 of input > 10 then
        set |ignoresInput| of parameters to true
end if
```

But, even if one did want to make sure that the `input` was only utilized if its contents met some condition, one could accomplish this same effect without having to read or alter the `|ignoresInput|` value; instead, one could simply declare their own boolean value for this purpose. So, I still think that the applicability of the `|ignoresInput|` `parameter` is questionable.

Similarly, I can't think of any particularly compelling reasons why one would need to read or modify the `source` `parameter` of their AppleScript while it runs.

---

## ***What else?***

One area of confusion for me still exists.

I still don't understand why Apple, in its documentation, advises against not returning anything in an AppleScript<sup>1</sup>:

> The template code finally returns `input` as its output; your action should always return something as output, even if it what [sic] is given it as input.

What's the harm of removing the `return` statement from one's AppleScript, if one does not need it?

If someone familiar with AppleScript methodology can address this matter for me, please drop a comment.

It is possible that I am misinterpreting the sentence.

I am interpreting this sentence to mean:

*"When writing your code, you should always make sure to include a `return` statement somewhere in your code."*

But, the sentence could potentially mean instead:

*"If you put a `return` statement in your code, that `return` statement is designed to always return something. If you don't assign anything to `input`, then the code will simply return the same input that it received."*

The ambiguity revolves around the original intent of the word, *should*, and whether the *should* is meant to act as a recommendation for the user writing an AppleScript, or whether, by *should*, they meant *will*.

---

Sources for passages included in this answer:

<sup>1. <sub>[Automator Programming Guide - *The Structure of the on run Command Handler*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/AutomatorConcepts/Articles/ImplementScriptAction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001512-97148-CJBIADBH)</sub></sup>

<sup>2. <sub>[Cocoa Scripting Guide - *Built-in Support for Basic AppleScript Types*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_about_apps/SAppsAboutApps.html)</sub></sup>

<sup>3. <sub>[AppleScript Language Guide - *Handler Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_handlers.html)</sub></sup>