# Automator: use filepath / filename in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, automator

In an automator app, there is a **Copy to Clipboard** and a **Run Apple Script**. If I assign this app to a certain file extension, by double clicking in Finder, the **Copy to Clipboard** function gets the filename properly, but how do I use file name and/or file folder in the apple script section below that? Both `$1` and `$@` seem to be empty.

Update:

Here is a new formulation of my question: I just need the name of the file inside the apple script. This should be passed to the block by Finder, but how can I access it?

[image]

In the above picture, I need to replace XXXXXX with a variable that let's me use the passed on filename inside the AppleScript.

Comment: The `do script` command doesn’t return the results of the script (that is what the Terminal does), but you would need to use the input to the **Run AppleScript** action.  What _exactly_ are you trying to do?

Comment: I like to replace `echo` with `cd`, that is change directory to the folder in which the file is located. Then I open that file in its own folder using another script. For that I need filename and folder. I am sure this variables are passed down as **Application Receives files and folders** indicates, and as **Copy To Clipboard** works, but I don't know how to catch the same variables in apple script.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280738/folder-path-of-select-file-in-applescript) is an example on StackOverflow on how to get the POSIX path of the selected file in AppleScript.

Comment: If the other script is also a shell script, there is the **Run Shell Script** action, which skips AppleScript and uses regular shell scripting and parameter expansion.

Comment: thanks, but I need to use Terminal. I just need the name of the file (and if possible its path) that is passed to the AppleScript block. How do I access these variables?

Comment: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270159/

Comment: ok, I see, with `display dialog input` I could see that`input` actually contains the file name that I am interested in. but its format is different, it has a lot of colons inside it instead of /. [here more on that](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AppleScript_Programming/Aliases_and_paths) must look further though.

Comment: I am one step closer: using `set fileName to (the POSIX path of input)` I have now the file name inside the AppleScript section. Now I need to somehow use it inside the `tell` section of the Terminal App.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the hint. Here is the final solution with explanation:

When double clicking on Finder, the `input` parameter will contain the alias of the file not its full path + name. The key is to convert it using

```
set fileName to (the POSIX path of input)
```

This new string, can then be used in the AppleScript section, but needs to be concatenated using `&` with other strings.

So, for example you can `cd` change directory to the directory that contains the file, like this:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set fileName to (the POSIX path of input)
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script with command "cd $(dirname " & fileName & ")"
    end tell
end run
```

[image]

Comment: Also note that `input` is a _list_, and you should also quote paths in case they contain spaces or other characters special to the shell.